# iOS - run 3rd party navigation app from code

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios7

I am new to iOS and I want to run navigation app from my own app. For now I just use this code:

```
- (void)navigationButtonTap:(id)sender
{
    Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
    if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)])
    {
        // Create an MKMapItem to pass to the Maps app
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate =
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([actualPlace.latitude doubleValue], [actualPlace.longitude doubleValue]);
        MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate
                                                       addressDictionary:nil];
        MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
        [mapItem setName:actualPlace.Name];
        // Pass the map item to the Maps app
        [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
    }
}
```

and it's working and I know how can I change it to run Apple maps with navigation started. It's okay but now I am thinking about some 3rd party options. How it's with other navigation apps like Google maps and others? Can iOS users set them as default and use them? How can I give user options to launch app which he wants?

I found [code for implementing Google Maps](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/how-to-launch-google-maps-or-apple-maps-from-an-ios-app/) option. But it's different code from Apple maps. Can I have same code for all navigation apps and then user decides which to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch 3rd party navigation apps and hand over an address or geo location only, when the other app conforms/implements an url schema. Some navigation apps actually do that.

Comment: And is there some default scheme for Apple maps and others?

Comment: Here for Apple Maps. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html  Later today I'll have a look at those url schemas for navigation apps that I found out last year sometime. Unless somebody else provides that information in the meantime.

Comment: But these are for Apple Maps only right? I can't use them to launch Google Maps? For every navigation app which I want to support I must implement their scheme, is it right? There isn't some default scheme which launch available options and then user choose which app to use?

Comment: I don't know about Google Maps out of the top of my head. But there are other navigation apps around that do provide an URL schema and therefore can be launched from within your app.

Comment: Google does, see here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=GM-for-iOS-sdk-1-7

Comment: Yes, I found it too. But I want to have some general solution to launch app which user wants. I am looking for some way how can I run some 3rd party without need to implement their own url scheme.

Comment: I guess that you will need to know all potenitally available url schemas. At least that is what we did because we, too, did not find a better way. Then you can check for each of the schemas if it is responded to - meaning if an app is installed. And then you can provide the user with a list of all available options e.g. in an action sheet.