# iOS support 3rd party navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapkit

In iOS 8 (maybe 7 too I can't recall) you can set default applications for navigation. I am currently implementing a button that allows a user to open up Apple Maps and get directions to a location the following way:

```
- (IBAction)getDirections:(id)sender {

CLLocationCoordinate2D endingCoord = storeLocation;
MKPlacemark *endLocation = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:endingCoord addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *endingItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:endLocation];
endingItem.name = @"Cubes Pizza Sunway";

NSMutableDictionary *launchOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[launchOptions setObject:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving forKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey];

[endingItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

}

This works great and launches how I'd expect. However, what if the user has Google Maps installed? Will Apple automatically give the user an option? Or do I need to implement an activity sheet and detect all the navigation apps and then figure out the URL schemas for each one?)

How would I go about implementing such a thing?

This is the same question: [iOS - run 3rd party navigation app from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767311/ios-run-3rd-party-navigation-app-from-code) but it's a year old and wanted to know if this feature was implemented by APPLE and if not how to implement checking if app is installed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Maps has a URL scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=GM-for-iOS-sdk-1-7) that you can use to launch the app. [Here is how you request directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=GM-for-iOS-sdk-1-7#display_directions). As described on their page you can check if the Google Maps app is installed via:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!)`

You'll also need to add `comgooglemaps` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` dictionary in your Info.plist to be able to use the `canOpenURL:` method on iOS 9, as described in [this blog post](http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes).

I believe the "default navigation app" you're thinking of is actually [a way for the user to manually switch other apps once they're in the built-in Maps app](http://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/how-to-force-ios-8-to-use-a-third-party-map-app/).

Comment: why dont we install the googlemaps sdk and show in a webview within our app, we ll have total control too

Comment: I haven't used the Google Maps SDK but I'm guessing that it's not going to have the full-app experience (especially for navigation) so linking to the app is probably a better experience for user, but that's down to the individual app I guess.